# Adding collection_action method to the top menu item in active admin in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using active admin gem in my project for admin section.

I have written a custom method using

collection_action :method_name do

//code goes here

end

Now I would like to add this method name to the menu item. How can I do that?

Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The collection_action will create the route and the action corresponding. If you need to be make this action available in your menu items you'll have to had the following lines

```
action_item only: :index do
  link_to 'Name the button', action: 'method_name'
end
```